# String from input is not converted (format error)

Tags: c#, string, vector

---

> IMPORTANT EDIT!!!!!!!
>   (I also edited the code)
>
> ---

I discovered that when i do `string[] pos = value.Split(',');` and the others, it does the correct thing, but here is the deal

In unity, decimals in string are represented by `,` so when i do `string[] pos = value.Split(',');`he splits by the first 3 commas he finds, and if you check the **Sample data** i just modified, and you split for the first 3 commas, you'll have the **Actual results**

I also managed to fix the scale

Original Post:

I'm trying to learn unity and I followed [this guide](https://youtu.be/P8EqD2atjJo?t=1209) in order to have a good save/load system (note that I deleted the line `value = value.Replace(" ","");` because it wasn't needed):

```
// Note: value is guaranteed to be a string of numbers in the format: "(1,2,3)"
public Vector3 StringToVector(string value)
{
     value = value.Trim('(', ')');
     value = value.Replace(" ","");
     string[] pos = value.Split(',');
     return new Vector3(float.Parse(pos[0]), float.Parse(pos[1]), float.Parse(pos[2]));
}
```

I think there is an error here because if i use said function in this other function, the X axis works just fine, the other two (Y and Z) ***do not***:

```
public virtual void Load(string[] values)
{        
    // in in the variable values[] i have in these positions:
    // values[0] objectname, values[1] (x,y,z) position, values[2] (x,y,z) scale
    transform.localPosition = SaveGameManager.Instance.StringToVector(values[1]);
    transform.localScale = SaveGameManager.Instance.StringToVector(values[2]);
}
```

---

**Sample data**

```
string position = "(190,0, 2,5, 180,0)";
string scale = "(5, 5, 5)";
```

**Expected results**
- position: `<190, 2.5, 180>`
- scale: `<5, 5, 5>`

**Actual results**
- position: `<190,0 0,0 2,0>`
- scale: `<5, 5, 5>`

Comment: I edited the original post, here it looks weird

Comment: Are you sure your input is what you think it is? It worked without changing anything. [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b5VNPG)

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the `Load` method and examine `values` to be sure the input is what you think. Then step through the code to see if something goes wrong.

Comment: @RufusL Unfortunately, I already tried and everything given in input to the Load function, works as intended

Comment: Well the code you posted works fine. Can you show the exact call to `Load` (including the string array values)?

Comment: The video is visual proof of what i do

Comment: Plus, it only works in 2D

Comment: There is a comment in the video, look for "Dave Johnson" with CTRL+F

The video guy never wrote anything about transform.quaternion lol

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a 99% solution.

```
value = value.Trim('(', ')');
value = value.Replace(" ","");
string[] pos = value.Split(',');
return new Vector3(float.Parse(pos[0]), float.Parse(pos[1]), float.Parse(pos[2]));
```

Add this piece of code right after `value = value.Replace(" ","");`

```
pos[0] = pos[0] + ',' + pos[1];
pos[2] = pos[2] + ',' + pos[3];
pos[4] = pos[4] + ',' + pos[5];
```

and substitute `return new Vector3(float.Parse(pos[0]), float.Parse(pos[1]), float.Parse(pos[2]));`

with `return new Vector3(float.Parse(pos[0]), float.Parse(pos[2]), float.Parse(pos[4]));`

This works because i simply put a comma where it should be, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

> In unity, decimals in string are represented by `,`

This is only true if your computer uses a locale where that is true. Unity uses `float.ToString()` in `Vector3.ToString()` and `float.ToString()` respects your PC's settings.

Try placing `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);` in the Awake function of any object in your scene to force US locale and period as a decimal separator.

EDIT: If you want to keep using commas as decimal separators, this should work:

```
string[] numbers = value
    .Replace("(", "")
    .Replace(")", "")
    .Replace(", ", "/")
    .Split('/');

Vector3 v = new Vector3(float.Parse(numbers[0]), float.Parse(numbers[1]), float.Parse(numbers[2]));
```